# Is it right to cast null to nullable when using ternary expression assigning to a nullable type?

Tags: c#, nullable

It feels strange to me to be casting null to a type so I wanted to double check that this is the right way to do this:

```
decimal? d = data.isSpecified ? data.Value : (decimal?)null;
```

[image]

[image]

NOTE: I am marking the answer that suggests the method that I personally like the best:

```
decimal? d = data.isSpecified ? data.Value : default(decimal?)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the cast. `decimal?` will accept a null, directly.

Comment: added screenshot for you reference.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, you are correct that `decimal?` will accept null, but the compiler needs to be able to determine the return type of the ternary expression, which it can only do if you cast null to `decimal?`.

Comment: added second screenshot for completeness, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. Alternatives:

```
condition ? (decimal?) value : null

condition ? new decimal?(value) : null

condition ? value : default(decimal?)

condition ? value : new decimal?()
```

Pick whichever you find most readable.

There's nothing you can do outside the expression itself, as it's the type of the expression which the compiler doesn't know. For example, putting the whole expression in brackets and casting it wouldn't help.

Comment: Would it work without the cast if `value` was already `decimal?` ?

Comment: @Robert: Yes, in that case it would be fine. The problem is that the type of the conditional expression *either* has to be the type of the LHS *or* the type of the RHS... and "null" doesn't have a type.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is `data.Value` of type `decimal`? If so, here's an alternative notation, without the cast:

```
decimal? d = data.isSpecified ? new decimal?(data.Value) : null;
```